# Capistrano deploying wrong version of my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano

I'm deploying a Rails 3.2.1 app with Capistrano to an Ubuntu/Passenger/Apache server. When I run `cap deploy`, it runs fine, but then when I visit my app in the browser, I can see that it's the version I was working with months ago, not the current version of my app.

Here is my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :user, "jason"
set :domain, "sniphq.com"
set :application, "Snip"
set :repository,  "/var/git/snip.git"

set :scm, "git"
set :branch, "master"
set :git_shallow_clone, true
set :scm_verbose, true

role :web, domain                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

set :deploy_to, "/home/jason/snip-cap"
set :deploy_via, :export

default_run_options[:pty] = true

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Why might this be happening?

Edit: What's interesting, and possibly helpful, is that I can follow the instructions [here](http://nathanhoad.net/deploy-from-a-git-tag-with-capistrano) and deploy my app from a certain Git tag. But obviously I don't want to create a new tag every time I deploy.

Comment: Make sure your changes are on the `master` branch. I've had your exact problem because I forgot to merge a feature branch back to master.

Comment: Thanks. I am on `master`, so I'm really puzzled as to why it's grabbing an old commit. I even double-checked that everything is pushed by creating a new clone from `/var/git/snip.git`. Sure enough, `snip.git` is up-to-date.

Comment: On a completely different note: Why aren't you interested in deploying a tag? It would seem more prudent, and would help with rolling back code more easily.

Comment: In theory I would agree that it seems like a good idea to release from tags. In practice, though, I've found that it doesn't always make sense. Sometimes I forget to include some tiny item in a release, and then I have to add a brand new tag just for a tiny little change.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had it pointed at the wrong repo.